# Flipping Sprite In The Update Loop

Tags: cocos2d-iphone

I've got a bird sprite that I want to bounce around the screen. So when it reaches the bounds of the screen, the bird will travel back and forth. This is working but I'm not able to flip the sprite each time.It works the first time it moves right and hits the right edge of the screen, and when it comes back and hits the left side, the sprite does not flip. Here's what I'm trying to do

```
- (void)update:(ccTime)dt
{

    if (bird_x > 1550 || bird_x < 0)
    {
        flip *= -1;
        self.bird.flipX = YES;
    }

    bird_x = bird_x + 10 * flip;
    _bird.position = ccp(bird_x, 1000);
}
```

What am I doing wrong?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because the flip is only an on/off state. Replace your `self.bird.flipX = YES;` line with `self.bird.flipX = !self.bird.flipX;` and try again.